# Receber um dado HTML via Web Socket do Arduino ESP32

Tags: html, http, arduino

Boa tarde. Estou desenvolvendo um projeto com o Arduino para realizar a contagem de pulsos quando uma requisição via um web socket HTTP criado pelo Arduino ESP32 for acionada. A requisição (no caso, quando o usuário apertar o botão na página) para iniciar a contagem já está implementada via GET/H. 
Contudo, eu gostaria de adicionar na página, usando HTML, um campo onde eu pudesse escrever um valor, e esse valor pudesse ser utilizado pelo programa no Arduino. Não tenho conhecimento profundo de HTML e front end, nem de como integrá-lo ao Arduino, então gostaria de saber se isso é viável, e se há algum material específico para esse tipo de estudo.

No código abaixo eu gostaria de adicionar uma variável "tempo" que fosse lida no servidor via html para ser utilizada na contagem de pulsos.

```
 //RUNS THE WEB SERVER AND COUNT THE PULSES DURING A SPECIFIED TIME 
void loop(){
  WiFiClient client;
  client = server.available();   // listen for incoming clients

  //CONNECT TO SERVER
  if (client){                              // if you get a client,
    Serial.println("New Client.");          // print a message out the serial port
    String currentLine = "";                // make a String to hold incoming data from the client
    while (client.connected()){             // loop while the client's connected
      if (client.available()){              // if there's bytes to read from the client,
        char c = client.read();             // read a byte, then
        Serial.write(c);                    // print it out the serial monitor
        if (c == '\n'){                     // if the byte is a newline character
          // if the current line is blank, you got two newline characters in a row.
          // that's the end of the client HTTP request, so send a response:
          if (currentLine.length() == 0){
            // HTTP headers always start with a response code (e.g. HTTP/1.1 200 OK)
            // and a content-type so the client knows what's coming, then a blank line:
            client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            client.println("Content-type:text/html");
            client.println();

            // the content of the HTTP response follows the header:
            client.print("Click <a href=\"/H\">here</a> to begin counter");

            // The HTTP response ends with another blank line:
            client.println();
            // break out of the while loop:
            break;
          }
          else{    // if you got a newline, then clear currentLine:
            currentLine = "";
          }
        } 
        else if (c != '\r') {  // if you got anything else but a carriage return character,
          currentLine += c;      // add it to the end of the currentLine
        }

        //READS THE REQUEST AND COUNT THE PULSES
        // Check to see if the client request was "GET /H":
        if (currentLine.endsWith("GET /H")) {

          while(timer <= tempo){
            timer = 0;
            if (timer > tempo){
              break;
            }

            timer = millis();
            //Serial.println(timer);
            delay(25);

            if (digitalRead(pin) > var){
              var = 1;
              pulse++;

              Serial.print(pulse);
              Serial.println(" pulses detected");
              while (digitalRead(pin) == HIGH);
            }
            else if (digitalRead(pin) == 0){
              var = 0;
            }
            delay(1);
           }
           //CONNECT TO IFTTT TO WRITE ON GOOGLE SHEETS
           initIFTTTrequest();
        }
      }
    }
    // close the connection:
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("Client Disconnected.");
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

[EXEMPLO DE COMPARTILHAMENTO DE DADOS COM HTML](https://capsistema.com.br/index.php/2020/02/02/servidor-da-web-esp32-dht11-dht22-temperatura-e-umidade-usando-o-arduino-ide/)

De modo geral a identificação de variáveis no HTML é feita usando a sintaxe %variavel%
Sendo que necessita fazer um código para escrever o conteúdo das variáveis, isso é, carregar quando lido o HTML.
E outro código para capturar a variável por POST ou GET ou javascript.